# Databricks Write Json file is too slow

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, writefile

I have simple scala snippet to read/write json files of total of 10GB (with mounting dir from storage account) --> it took 1.7 hour with almost all the time in the write json file line.

Cluster setup:

- Azure Databricks DBR 7.3 LTS, spark 3.0.1, scala 2.12
- 11 workers + one driver of type Standard_E4as_v4 (each has 32.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores)

1. Why writing is too slow?
2. Is not writing is parallelized as reading accross partitions/workers?
3. How to speed writing or the whole process up?

Code for mount dir:

```
val containerName = "containerName"
val storageAccountName = "storageAccountName"
val sas = "sastoken"
val config = "fs.azure.sas." + containerName+ "." + storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net"

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://containerName@storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/myfile",
  extraConfigs = Map(config -> sas))
```

Code for read/write json files:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._

val jsonDF = spark.read.json("/mnt/myfile")
jsonDF.write.json("/mnt/myfile/spark_output_test")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using "I would say" better spark apis, like
read --> spark.read.format("json").load("path")
write --> res.write.format("parquet").save("path)
and writing in parquet format as it is compressed and very optimized for spark

Comment: then it's better to use Delta, that based on the Parquet, and has more optimizations